# Expo eject blocked at choosing android name project

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I'm trying to eject an freshly created app with expo init without any changes unsuccessfully, nothing happens after typing android package name.
I've tried com.user.app, com.app , something.com but nothing worked.

```
Environment
System:
OS: macOS 12.1
Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 16.13.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.17 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 8.5.5 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 2022.03.21.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 21.2, iOS 15.2, macOS 12.1, tvOS 15.2, watchOS 8.3
Android SDK:
API Levels: 28, 29, 30, 31
Build Tools: 29.0.0, 29.0.1, 29.0.2, 29.0.3, 30.0.0, 30.0.1, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 32.0.0
System Images: android-28 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-30 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-31 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-31 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2020.3 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7784292
Xcode: 13.2.1/13C100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
expo: ~44.0.0 => 44.0.6
react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
react-dom: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
react-native: 0.64.3 => 0.64.3
react-native-web: 0.17.1 => 0.17.1
npmGlobalPackages:
expo-cli: 5.3.0
Expo Workflow: managed
```

Reproducible demo or steps to reproduce from a blank project

```
expo init
expo eject or expo prebuild
```

I also tried with expo-cli version 4.13.0 and version 3.28.6

Answer (score 0):

I  had the same issue and resolved by adding the following to the app.json.

```
  "ios”: 
         {
           "bundleIdentifier": "projectname",
          "buildNumber": "1.0.0"
         }
        
   "android": 
   
        {
          "package": "projectname",
          "versionCode": 1 , 
        }
```

Go to the terminal and try expo eject again and enter the project name saved above.